# Freeplane reports it's not compatible with Java 10 when attempting to install and run on Ubuntu 18 how do I resolve?

Tags: java

I have been trying to install mindmapping software on Ubuntu 18 Bionic Beaver now for the last 3 days.  I'm getting a little weary from all of the application research and many, many failed install and run attempts for various mindmapping s/w.  I first tried to install XMind8 and then XMind 7.5 and could not get it to run even though I followed 4 dif "solution instructions"  I gave up because I realized that many people were having the same problem and asking for the same help.  I figured the XMind folks, just wasn't going to make it easy for use to install their product.  Now I'm started on Freeplane 1.7.7.  I am certain it's the lasted version.  I did the unzip and execution command 
sh freeplan.sh
and I get this error message:  Dialog box heading -->  "Incompatible JRE version"  and in the dialog box "Freeplane is not compatible with Java 10, exiting"

I did the command         java -version     in the terminal window to verify that yes ai am running java 10.

How do I get Freeplane 1.7.7 to work on my computer without uninstalling Java 10 which seems to be the default and latest JDK for Ubuntu 18??  I really want to get started with my mindmapping and I am at my limit of doing things to resolve my issue.  Please someone help me!!!  I believe Freeplane 1.7.7 needs JDK version 8.  I don't want to disrupt anything else that is going on where other applications may need JDK 10.  Thank You in advance.

Comment: @Pulszar, Thank You!!!  I regret to say, I gave up.  I had lost so much time.   I was doggedly determined to complete the install and that's why I stuck with it for so many hours in so many days.  I wanted mind mapping software to firm up my ideas and to increase my productivity.  I was not productive for the 3 days even though I put in mega hours fueled my me determination.  I kept saying it's got to be easy, they want us to use their software.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more then one Java installation on your Ubuntu. You can install Java 8 (1.8) next to Java 10 (Java 11).

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

**See if you can point somehow only Freeplane 1.7.7 to start with java 8. If there is configuration file (inside Freeplane 1.7.7) with java virtual machine path or something. If you can set it to the Java 8.**

If not then you can try to put Java 8 as default and see if you have some problems.
**Attention: you can get some problems with other programs that use Java 10 (Java 11) if you execute the next steps!**

For more information how to do it in section (Managing Java): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04

I hope I don't miss some steps but first you set which should be the default Java.

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Also many programs need to know `JAVA_HOME`. You have to set it for your Java version.

Check again which is your active version:

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Java default install directories are:

```
OpenJDK 11 is located at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java.

OpenJDK 8 is located at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java.

Oracle Java 8 is located at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java.
```

You have to set it inside: `/etc/environment`

`sudo nano /etc/environment`

then add in the end of the file you active Java 8 installation

`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"`

or

`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java"`

And then reload:

`source /etc/environment`

And check if it correct:

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

Check if your program is working. If you see something broken you can set it back to Java 11.

Good luck to all!